# How to add private repo which I don't owned on docker hub for auto build

Tags: docker, github, dockerhub

I want to use docker hub to do an auto build on every commits sent to github. It works fine for the git repo owned by my account. What if there is a private git repo and I have the write access, that repo doesn't appear on the docker hub when I search git repos under my account. Is there a way to add the git repo on docker hub for auto-build?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to fork that repo (it would still be private) and set that repo on Docker Hub (warning: you only get *one* private repo for free, after that you would need to [buy a plan](https://hub.docker.com/billing-plans/))

Then you can put in place:

- a [GitHub webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) on the original repo
- a [webhook listener](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/configuring/) that would receive any push event sent by the webhook.

For each push event, you would pull on your local fork, then push it to your remote fork, monitored by Docker Hub.